# Unable to mount RAID 0 drive

Tags: raid0

When I run the following command:

```
 sudo dmraid -ay
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: opening "/dev/mapper/isw_cigjeghbef_RAID 0"
```

And, after attempting to open the drive in the file explorer, I get the following error in a dialog box:

```
Error mounting /dev/dm-1 at /media/NAME/RAID 0: 
Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" 
                    -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177"
                       "/dev/dm-1" "/media/NAME/RAID 0"' 
exited with non-zero exit status 21: fuse: mount failed: No such file or directory
```

Trying to open a raid 0 drive.

**EDIT**: I am running Linux Mint, my entire parts list is [posted here](http://pcpartpicker.com/p/mWrR3C).

Comment: voldenoir: Did you *really* get a single-line error message that is 268 characters long?  If not, please [edit] your question to show what happened.  Use code formatting rather than quote formatting.

Comment: Hi G-Man, I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says I gess the directory where you want to mount it is obviously not there so you need to create it for example `mount -t ntfs  /dev/yourraid //mnt/mounthere` as in the `/mnt/mounthere` directory you have to create it.
And let me know how did you created the raid under the mint so I can help you out more 
**edit** Oh I realice maybe you have to scape the space between the RAID 0 like

```
RAID\ 0
```